# listbox having buttons as data template does not display content from server

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using expression blend 2012 for my windows phone app....I have created a list in which content has to be displayed in buttons from the server database...but my output shows blank buttons without any content...please help
my xaml code

```
XAML

<ListBox x:Name="lstUniversity" Height="532" FontSize="30" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=University}"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1,0,1,110">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1">
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                    Height="100" Width="550"
                    FontSize="24" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and my c# code is

```
public class University
{

   public string Name { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
{
   Universities = new List<University>();
{
   try
   {
      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mastertionary.com/ios/connect1.php");
      webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new     DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
  webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}     }

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs     e)
{
   try
   {
      List<University> Universities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<University>>(e.Result);
      foreach (University em in Universities)
      {

         string Name = em.Name;
         lstUniversity.Items.Add(Name);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems with your Xaml:

1. The listbox ItemSource binding (ItemsSource="{Binding Path=University}"), is meant to bind your listbox contents to the list of items you want to display. This needs to be something like ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Universities}", where Universities is an ObservableCollection of University objects.
2. Universities must be a property of your data context, and should have a NotifyPropertyChanged method. The NotifyPropertyChanged method is what triggers the binding to occur.
   Alternatively, you can remove the ItemSource binding and add the items directly to the list as you are doing in the DownloadedStringCompleted function - but you cannot do both (which is what your code is doing now).

However, you need to make a few more corrections:

1. Notice that you are adding string objects to lstUniversities.Items, but your Button's DataTemplate is binding to the Name property of whatever object is in the list. So you either need to add the University objects to the list (not the strings) because University has a Name property or remove the Name binding.

Note that the DataContext for a listbox item is whatever object is in the lstUniversities.Items collection, so in this case a string.

To simplify things, since your University class has only one property, Name, why don't you do the following:

1. Keep your code in the DownloadStringCompleted function ==> here you are manually adding the items (in this case strings) instead of binding the listbox items source to an ObservableCollection of University objects (note: you might want to clear the Items list before you add items to it)
2. Change your XAML to the XAML below - I've removed the ItemsSource binding and the Name binding

2a. The ItemsSource binding interferes because you are manually populating the ItemsSource and it is also wrong because it binds to a University object not an ObservableCollection of University objects.

2b. The Name binding doesn't work because you are adding strings to the listbox's Items Source and a string does not have a Name property

2c. Any property you want to bind to must use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Since you are no longer binding to a property this is not necessary, but if do add bindings you should look this up in MSDN and learn how to use it.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstUniversity" Height="532" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1,0,1,110">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1">
            <Button Content="{Binding}" 
                    Height="100" Width="550"
                    FontSize="24" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your `ItemsSource` binding didn't work and your listbox populated manually from code by adding string to it's `Items` property.

In this case, the *easiest way* (not necessarily the best) to fix it is by changing the button `Content` binding to :

```
<Button Content="{Binding}" 
    ... />
```